# How to properly store to a hashmap and then copy over to a treemap to loop and display the key and values

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I am storing user input into a hashmap then using it to build a Treemap from it to and then loop through and display key/values inside. Instead I only manage to store/display the 2 most recent user data entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Lab09 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int studentNbr = 0;
        int scoreNbr = 0;
        String name = "";

        HashMap<String, Integer> students = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


        System.out.println("How many students do you want to enter?");
        studentNbr = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("How many scores do you want to enter for each student?");
        scoreNbr = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < studentNbr; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter student number " + (i+1) + " name:");
            name = input.nextLine();
            int j = 0;
            while(j < scoreNbr){
                System.out.println("Enter score " + (j+1) + " for " + name + ":");
                students.put(name, input.nextInt());
                input.nextLine();
                j++;
            }

        }
        Map<String, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(students);
        for (String i : sorted.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key: " + i + " value: " + sorted.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

I expect to be able to display all key/values but instead only receive 2 lines displaying the most recent user input instead of all the data put in by the user.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the scores of each student? To show the average or to show all the scores? In your code you just store the latest submitted score for each student

Comment: Correct, I wanted to store the scores of each student but was not aware that hashMap replaced the previous value if the key was the same as @Peeyush answer helped clarify this for me and solution helped achieve my goal.

Comment: Why? Why use the `HashMap` at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HashMap in java will replace previous 'value' with new 'value' if 'key' is same. You can create composite key for 'students' map with student name and score id. e.g.

```
  students.put(name+'-'+j, input.nextInt());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a list of scores as a value. And you can directly use `TreeMap` at first place without having to define two map instances.
Here the (relevant) code:

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> students = new TreeMap<>();        

    for(int i = 0; i < studentNbr; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter student number " + (i+1) + " name:");
        name = input.nextLine();
        int j = 0;
        while(j < scoreNbr){
            System.out.println("Enter score " + (j+1) + " for " + name + ":");
            students.putIfAbsent(name, new ArrayList<>());
            students.get(name).add(input.nextInt());
            input.nextLine();
            j++;
        }
    }
```